# Using LIKE Condition getting values but how to get Non values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Names 
(name varchar(1),
Surname Varchar(1))


CREATE TABLE FullNames 
(Fullname varchar(1),
Surname Varchar(1))
```

Now I'm checking with Information_Schema.columns to get the Column names

```
select 
TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where 
COLUMN_NAME like '%name%' 

TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME
Names           name
Names           Surname
FullNames       Fullname
FullNames       Surname
```

but I use another like condition

```
where COLUMN_NAME like '%name%' or COLUMN_NAME like '%Noname%'
```

then I want to get the result

```
  TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME
    Names           name
    Names           Surname
    FullNames       Fullname
    FullNames       Surname
    NULL             NULL
```

Can you please help.

Comment: What does the `NULL, NULL` record represent? If you want a null row, you can `union` it to the result set. But I think you want something else...

Comment: if I'm Checking with Like Condition which have no column or table created in Database but I'm Checking in like condition I should get NULL for COLUMN_NAME like '%Noname%'

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @HoneyBadger in first condition I have column names I got result set and in second like condition I don't have column names. Even though I should show NULL for No columns

Comment: In your example you only have columns `like '%name%'`, so the `null` row has no reference. It means nothing. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find where columns have no name use:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME like '%name%'
OR
    COLUMN_NAME IS NULL;
```

Or if you just want to add a row with `NULL` in wherever the `COLUMN_NAME` is like `'NoName'` then use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COLUMN NAME LIKE '%NoName%' THEN NULL ELSE TABLE_NAME END,
    CASE WHEN COLUMN NAME LIKE '%NoName%' THEN NULL ELSE COLUMN_NAME END 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME like '%name%'
OR
    COLUMN_NAME like '%NoName%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to find tables with null column names? Can that even occur? Something like:

`where COLUMN_NAME like '%name%' or COLUMN_NAME is null`

Answer (score 0):

As others I'm not 100% sure what you are after so here isa  quick stab at it.....

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_NAME like '%name%'
UNION ALL
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_NAME like '%noname%'
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, NULL
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%noname%' )
```